# Add a blank row in flextable

Tags: r, flextable

When creating tables in Word reports, I often want to add blank rows in between variables. As a trivial toy example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(officer)
library(flextable)
```

```
doc <- read_docx()
```

```
table_no_breaks <- mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl)
```

```
table_no_breaks_ft <- flextable(table_no_breaks)
```

```
doc <- doc %>% 
  body_add_flextable(table_no_breaks_ft) %>% 
  body_add_par("")
```

Results in a table that looks like this:

[image]

I can add line breaks directly to the data frame like this:

```
table_breaks <- table_no_breaks %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      everything(),
      as.character
    )
  ) %>% 
  add_row(cyl = NA, n = NA, .after = 1) %>% 
  add_row(cyl = NA, n = NA, .after = 3) %>%
  add_row(cyl = NA, n = NA, .after = 5)
```

```
table_breaks_ft <- flextable(table_breaks)
```

```
doc <- doc %>% 
  body_add_flextable(table_no_breaks_ft) %>% 
  body_add_par("") %>% 
  body_add_flextable(table_breaks_ft)
```

```
print(doc, "flextable.docx")
```

Which results in the Word table that I want:

[image]

However, I would prefer to be able to add the blank rows directly to the flextable rather than the data frame the flextable is built from. To me, this is a formatting issue rather than a data issue, and I prefer to keep data issues (manipulation of data frames) and formatting issues (manipulation of Word tables) separate. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Four months late, but as far as I can see your solution (adding blank rows) is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Very late to this but what if you just add padding to the table example below? Is the issue that you want actual blank rows or just spacing between rows?

```
library(dplyr)
 library(flextable)
 
 table_no_breaks <- mtcars %>% 
   count(cyl)
 
 
 table_breaks <- table_no_breaks %>% 
   mutate(
     across(
       everything(),
       as.character
     ))
 
 
 flextable(table_no_breaks) |> 
    padding(padding = 15, part = "all")
```

[image: padded table]

edit: if you want to only pad certain rows you can use the `i` and `j` inputs to specify certain rows and columns to pad. Example below:

```
flextable(table_no_breaks) |> 
  padding(i= 2, padding = 15, padding.top = TRUE) |> 
  align(align = "center", part = "all")
```

[image: pad row]

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you for the suggestion! I think that does technically work for the example I posted and I'm sure it will be helpful to some people. In reality, I don't actually want a break between EVERY row. I want a break between certain rows. For example, education level (<hs, hs, college) -> blank row -> income (<50K, 50-100, >100).

Comment: I added an example that will pad specific rows by using the `i` input to the `padding()` function.